# CollectionView Content View does not update/ refresh when viewdidload

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I want to have [this progression view (pod)](https://github.com/maxkonovalov/MKRingProgressView) inside each collectionviewcell. When I run the app, the progression is 0%, it should animate to 100% for testing, but it stays at 0%. Only when I swipe up and down (refresh the cells???) it starts animating to 100%. This is my code:

```
    import UIKit
import MKRingProgressView

class myCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var ringView: UIView!
    let ringsize = 150
    var ringProgressView = RingProgressView()
    override func layoutSubviews() {
         ringProgressView = RingProgressView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: ringsize, height: ringsize))
        ringProgressView.startColor = .red
        ringProgressView.endColor = .magenta
        ringProgressView.ringWidth = CGFloat(ringsize) * 0.15
        ringProgressView.progress = 0.0
        ringProgressView.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        ringView.addSubview(ringProgressView)
    }
}

extension myCollectionViewCell{
    func setProgress(progress: Double){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5){
            self.ringProgressView.progress = progress
        }
    }
}


    import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class myCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var cellColor = true
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return 7
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! myCollectionViewCell
    
        cell.setProgress(progress: 1.0)
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]
Can someone help me? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `myCollectionView.reloadData()` inside `viewDidAppear` method.

Comment: I stays at 0% :(

Comment: Can you test calling it inside `viewDidAppear` method?